# Why use **head (and not *head) in RemoveHead(node) function?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

In most of the explanations in the book the author insists of using **list passing  instead of *list, however as per my understanding I feel there is nothing wrong in *list.  Please someone explain me in detail if i am wrong. For example, to delete head of a linked  list, the author says the below code is wrong.

```
void RemoveHead(node *head)
{
   node *temp = head-> next; /* line 1 */
   free(head);
   head = temp;
}
```

Instead he says the below code must be used

```
void RemoveHead(node **head)
{
   node *temp = (*head)-> next;
   free(*head);
   *head = temp;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a C than C++ question. In C++ you should probably pass `node *&`, but I am not removing the task as I have seen that way too many times in actual C++ code.

Comment: My signature would have been `node *RemoveHead(node *head)` but ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. When you want to modify a integer variable inside a function, you pass it by reference. That is, you pass its address.

```
int x = 5;

void modify_value (int* x)
{
    (*x) = 7; // is not 5 anymore
}
```

With pointers is the same. If you want to modify a pointer. You have to pass it by reference. That is, you have to pass its address. Which is a pointer to a pointer.

```
int* ptr_x = &x;

void modify_pointer (int** ptr_x)
{
    *ptr_x = NULL; // is not &x anymore
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In your first example:

```
head = temp;
```

Does nothing outside the function, it only sets the local variable `head` to `temp` inside the function. Whatever variable the caller passed in will remain unchanged. The author is correct, you need to use pointers or (better) references (if you're using C++).

Answer (score 3):

When passing a `node*` as the argument, you can free, and modify the **contents** of the memory address pointed by that pointer. However, modifications performed on the pointer itself will not be seen from outside the function, since the pointer is passed by value.

On you second example, since you are passing a pointer to the head pointer, you can actually modify the actual head pointer, not just the memory pointed by it.

So in your second function, when `*head = temp;` is executed, you are modifying the address to which the pointer passed as argument points to.

Therefore, the author is right.

Answer (score 3):

Author is right. ** is effectively pass by reference (i.e. you can change 'head').

In your version (pass by value), head remains unchanged in the calling code.

Answer (score 2):

The author is correct.  In your first example, you're modifying a local copy of `head` - the caller won't notice that anything has changed.  `head` will still have been freed, so you're on track for a crash in pretty short order.  You need to pass a pointer to modify the caller's variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.. can you please explain with an example.. sorry i am confused